# What is the default email server for Teamcity 7.1?

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, teamcity-7.0

Without any changes, email notifications stopped being sent from our continuous integration server which is a Teamcity 7.1 server.  Up to now I've just used the default teamcity email configuration, which was this:

```
SMTP host: mail 
SMTP port: 25 
Send email messages from: Teamcity 
SMTP login: <blank> 
SMTP password: <blank>
Secure connection: none
```

Worked fine for last year or so.  Now I'm trying to diagnose what is wrong, but I don't really know what the above configuration is doing... Is it pointing to a built-in mail server that is bundled with Teamcity?  Is it pointing to the company's exchange server?  Something else?

Comment: Nikita's answer was correct and helpful.  Figured out my root problem as well.  Turns out that the company mail server started requiring that the "from" address be of the form 'something@companyname.com'.  Once I did that notifications started working again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Teamcity does not have any bundled mail servers. This configuration point to your company's SMTP server. By occasion, SMTP server's name is 'mail'. So TC tries to connect to mail:25 and send messages 'from' 'Teamcity'

Please check if SMTP server's authentication settings were modified (e.g., anonymous access is now forbidden). Also please check 'teamcity-server.log' for error messages related to sending notifications.

Comment: Thanks.  That answers my question, but still have the problem.  Mail server is not requiring authentication.  Downloaded a simple java mail client (Pooka) and was able to send an email using mail:25.  No errors in the logs.  Is there a way to change the log level to show if an email was even attempted?

Comment: Found out how to turn on debug logging in teamcity.  See here: http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD65/TeamCity+Server+Logs#TeamCityServerLogs-loggingPreset.

Comment: Also fixed my issue.  See comment on OP.